# How to replace a string at a particular postion in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    string q1 = "What [replace string] years? ";

In the above question I want to replace "years of study" with `model.values` 
so my required output should be as:

    string q1 = "What [replace string] years?";
```

where "2013,2014" will be coming from database .

So I need to append values to the static question ,the values will be coming from database using mvc models.

How to replace a string at a particular position i stuck there any suggestions it will help me thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the type of Model.values?

Comment: @Fabjan I would use string.Join(",", Model.values).  depending on the number of values in Model it may be more efficient because it uses a StringBuilder internally.  you method is going to create a new string for iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use string.Format()

change you q1 declaration to this

```
string q1 = "What type of legal entity was the Company during the {0} tax years? ";
```

Then format the string

```
var q2 = string.Format(q1, <replacement  string>);
```

with `<replacement string>` being the values you are substituting

So,

```
var q2 = string.Format(q1, model.Values);
```

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN

Comment: it worked but small doubt i need to append more values like

Comment: what type of legal entity was the company during 2013,2014,2016 tax years like these

Comment: need to check null or empty

Comment: you can add a conditional null check to check your values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $ c# 6.0 feature

```
$"What type of legal entity was the Company during the {Model.values} tax years? "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This :-

```
  string q2=  String.Format("What type of legal entity was the Company during the {0} tax years? ", YourModelName.Years);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `string.Replace`

```
string q1 = "What type of legal entity was the Company during the [years of the study] tax years? ";
q1 = q1.Replace("[years of the study]", someValue.ToString());
```

However, this is not a very good practice. Using `string.Format`, as others suggested is better.